# How to split an hexagon into multiple buttons in HTML/CSS/JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, shapes

I'm building a wep application for a client, with a specific requirement for its **button shape**.

The client wants a responsive **list of buttons encapsulated in an hexagon**, like the example in the following image.

Each button is a trapezoid (except for the one in the middle), but my knowledge for CSS shapes is near-zero.

**Example buttons shape**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5ktM.png

So far, I've found how to draw an hexagon, and a trapezoid shaped button (following CSS code), but I don't know how to blend them together in a nice and responsive way.

Code for a trapezoid button:

```
.trapezoid {
  width: 230px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 0; 
  position: relative;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 40px solid #2963BD;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Code for an hexagon

```css
.hexagon
{   overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(120deg);
    transform: rotate(120deg);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Any help or starting point would be appreciated, thanks !

Comment: SVG would be the most logical method

Comment: I didn't know about this technology for html buttons, I'll look into it but it seems promising, thx